# Прописная буква в слове "кремль"

Tags: прописная-строчная

Когда речь идет о Кремле, расположенном в Москве, то мы всегда пишем это слово с прописной буквы: Московский Кремль. Но, как известно, кремлей в России гораздо больше одного. И, например, если речь идет о кремле из Нижнего Новгорода или Казани, то уже пишем со строчной. Почему так?
А еще было бы интересно узнать, чем кремль отличается от крепости? Например, знаменитый Пражский Град зовут то кремлем, то крепостью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**кремль** (крепость в старых русских городах) и **Кремль** (район города, архит. комплекс; правительственная резиденция в Москве); **Московский Кремль**; но: **Новгородский кремль, Псковский кремль, Рязанский кремль** и т. п.
(Из орфографического словаря).

**КРЕМЛЬ**, -я; м.

1. Внутренняя городская крепость в старинных русских городах. *Новгородский к. Московский к.*
2. [с прописной буквы]
   Место размещения аппарата президента на территории Московского Кремля. Президент работает в Кремле. /
   О власти центрального правительства. Действовать по указке Кремля. < Кремлёвский, -ая, -ое. К-ие стены. К-ие башни.
   (Из Большого толкового словаря Кузнецова).

Так что Пражский Град не совсем правильно называть кремлём.

В Новгороде кремль называют *детинец*, в Пскове – *кром*.